# Change tableview header height inside a collection

Tags: ios, swift, uitableview, uicollectionview

How can I make size of header of `UITableView` inside `UICollectionView` dynamic. I have used this code before to make `UITableView` header dynamic inside UIViewController

```
 override func viewDidLayoutSubviews() {
       super.viewDidLayoutSubviews()
       sizeHeaderToFit()
   }

   func sizeHeaderToFit() {
       let headerView = questionTableView.tableHeaderView!

       headerView.setNeedsLayout()
       headerView.layoutIfNeeded()

       let height = headerView.systemLayoutSizeFitting(UIView.layoutFittingCompressedSize).height
       var frame = headerView.frame
       frame.size.height = height
       headerView.frame = frame

       questionTableView.tableHeaderView = headerView
   }
```

But cannot use this code inside `UICollectionViewCell` class.  It says 'UICollectionViewCell' has no member `viewDidLayoutSubviews`.

So how can I make dynamic header height of tableView inside collectionView. I have dragged `UIView` at top (for headerview) in `UITableView` in storyboard

Comment: You can not use `viewDidLayoutSubviews` in `UICollectionViewCell` because it is part of `UIViewController`.

Comment: How can I do similar functionality for UItableView Embedded in UICollectionView @PALAKMobileTeamLeader

Comment: did you try to make header view with help of func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, viewForHeaderInSection section: Int) -> UIView?{}

Comment: Yes it makes other view in uitableview? Eg: Header view in Storyboard, headerview height from this delegate, then showing cells

Comment: it is better if you share more code of table view so i can help u in better way.

Comment: Table view is embedded in collectionview. So all its datasource and delegate methods are in collectionview. Also outlet is in collectionview Cell. 
In think I have shared all the necessary details

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/209738/discussion-between-palak-mobile-team-leader-and-ios).

Answer (score 0):

Most important message is you need to call all delegate and datasource method of UITableViewController in UICollectionViewCell.swift file.

```
  var intDynamicHeight = CGFloat()

  func sizeHeaderToFit() -> CGFloat
  {
   let headerView = questionTableView.tableHeaderView!

   //headerView.setNeedsLayout()
   //headerView.layoutIfNeeded()

   let height = headerView.systemLayoutSizeFitting(UIView.layoutFittingCompressedSize).height

   self.intDynamicHeight = height
  // var frame = headerView.frame
  // frame.size.height = height
  // headerView.frame = frame

  // questionTableView.tableHeaderView = headerView

  return height
}


  func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, heightForHeaderInSection section: Int) -> CGFloat 
{
    return self.sizeHeaderToFit()
}


func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, viewForHeaderInSection section: Int) -> UIView?
{
        let headerView = questionTableView.tableHeaderView!
        let viewNewIN = UIView.init(frame: CGRect(x: 0, y: 0, width: <Your desire Width>, height: self.intDynamicHeight))
        headerView.isHidden = false
       var frame = headerView.frame
       frame.size.height = height
       headerView.frame = frame

       viewNewIN.addSubview(headerView)

       return viewNewIN
}
```

And hide your header view in Initial stage than display in `viewForHeaderInSection` method.